# Are there any free or low cost disassemblers for the Renesas H8 family of processors?

Tags: tools, disassembly, renesas-h8

IDA Pro can deal with the Renesas H8 processors, but not the free version.

Are there any free or low cost (<£100) disassemblers for the Renesas H8 family or processors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an H8 port of GNU binutils (the target is called 'h8300' I believe) which includes `objdump`. It seems it's even available in Debian in the package [`binutils-h8300-hms`](http://packages.debian.org/sid/binutils-h8300-hms) (might be outdated).

Alternative GNU-based toolchains for many Renesas processors (including H8) are provided by [KPIT](http://www.kpitgnutools.com/) (free but requires registration). I think they've been contributing to mainline too but not sure how's their progress there.

Just for reference, here's how to use `objdump` to disassemble a raw binary:

```
objdump -m h8300 -b binary -D myfile.bin
```

Renesas offers their own commercial compiler/assembler/simulator (and I *think* a disassembler too) suite called [High-performance Embedded Workshop](http://am.renesas.com/products/tools/coding_tools/c_compilers_assemblers/h8_compiler/index.jsp) (HEW) but I couldn't find out how much it costs. There is a [downloadable evaluation version](http://am.renesas.com/support/downloads/download_results/C2000301-C2000400/evaluation_h8c.jsp), however.

For a quick look at some hex you can also try the [Online Disassembler](http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/run_hex), it has a couple of H8 variants.

Answer (score 6):

[dah8300](http://www.pcuf.fi/~rak/computing/h8/dah8300/index.php) is a free disassembler for Renesas H8 binaries, and its [source code is also freely available](http://www.pcuf.fi/~rak/computing/h8/dah8300/dah8300.4th).