# Bin format of H8300

Tags: objdump, renesas-h8

I am trying to analyze some binary files that are supposedly from a H8300 processor. I found [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/are-there-any-free-or-low-cost-disassemblers-for-the-renesas-h8-family-of-proces) that mentioned objdump supports H8300 but when I use the command I get the following error:

> objdump: can't use supplied machine h8300

I guess the files does not have the right format. From what I can see, they have the following format:

```
BeginLine
Address:HexData:ChecksumByte?
EndLine
```

I also tried to export the HexData to a bin file but I still get the same error. What is the expected format?

[image]
[image]